# java.io.FileNotFoundException when writing to internal memory

Tags: java, android

I've written some functions for making/editing the files and they worked fine. However, I needed to use these function in many activities, so I've found the guide on how to globalize functions, and somehow did it. But after I put my functions in the separate class, they stopped working. My logcat is not working, so I can't trycatch it, but even if I could, I don't think it would help me.

Here is part of MainActivity.java:

```
MyHelper myHelp = new MyHelper(this);
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
myHelp.synchronizedb("filename");
}
```

Here is part of MyHelper.java:

```
public class MyHelper extends ActionBarActivity {
Context mContext;

public MyHelper(Context context){
    this.mContext = context;
}
public void writeFile(String fname, String fcontent) {
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput(fname, MODE_APPEND)));
        bw.write(fcontent);
        bw.close();
}



public void synchronizedb(String filename) {
    writeFile(filename, "blabla");
}
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Compile error? run-time error? Exception thrown? Not what you expect to see in your output file?

Comment: This code doesn't compile; `writeFile()` should throw `IOException`.

Comment: Also, you call something called `synchrondb`, but your helper has a method called `synchronizedb`.

Comment: java.io.FileNotFoundException. Why should writeFile throw it?

Comment: This is the kind of problem which is not solved by examining debug output (even if available, it would only tenuously hint at the real problem), but rather by recognizing that it is a case of misuse of Android API components.

Answer (score 0):

You are improperly making a class which is not utilized like an Activity subclass extend ActionBarActivity.  It is not workable to call `new` for any subclass of Activity, as only an Activity which has been created by the system will be fully functional, and only *after* its onCreate() method has been called by the system.

Likely you hit upon making your helper class a sort of fake Activity, in order to be able to use methods inherited from Activity (and similar) such as openFileOutput().  But that is not workable.

A more workable solution is to drop the "extends ActionBarActivity" from your class name, and either utilize the passed in context reference:

```
mContext.openFileOutput(...)
```

Or, perhaps even better, discovered the internal storage location in the constructor and save that for later use:

```
public class MyHelper {
  Context mContext;
  File mDir;

    public MyHelper(Context context){
        this.mContext = context;
        this.mDir = context.getFilesDir();
    }
    public void writeFile(String fname, String fcontent) {
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
               new FileOutputStream(new File(mDir, fname), MODE_APPEND)));
            bw.write(fcontent);
            bw.close();
    }
```

Further, because of that rule about an Activity class only being fully functional after it's onCreate() is called, you must move your creation of the helper class into or after the utilizing Activity's onCreate()

```
MyHelper myHelp; //can't initialize as our context is not yet valid
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    myHelp = new MyHelper(this); //now we have a working context to pass
    myHelp.synchronizedb("filename");
}
```